# Specifying that authorization is required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm somewhat new to MVC (but not ASP.NET). Is there a similar concept in MVC as there is in ASP.NET to specify URL authorization?

The question is really related to Facebook C# SDK - they have introduced the `[CanvasAuthorize]` attribute, which applies to a controller in the MVC app. How can I apply `[CanvasAuthorize]` to a set of controllers without attaching this attribute to each one?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have all those controllers derive from a base controller and then decorate this base controller with the attribute which will make it apply to all controllers and actions. In ASP.NET MVC 3 you also have the possibility to use [global action filters](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/10/30/asp-net-mvc-3-using-global-action-filters-to-find-out-running-time-of-controller-actions.aspx) and [custom filter providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ifilterprovider.aspx).